# Powershell return only sunrise/sunset time

Tags: powershell

I am using a rest API to return the sunrise and sunset times for my location.

```
$Daylight = (Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=35.608237&lng=-78.647497").results
$Sunrise  = ($Daylight.Sunrise | Get-Date -Format HH:mm).ToLocalTime()
$Sunset  = ($Daylight.Sunset | Get-Date -Format HH:mm).ToLocalTime()
```

However, the output needs to be formatted to only provide the time and not the full date.  I've tried adding `-format hh:mm` (as shown above) but it errors out:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'ToLocalTime'.
At line:3 char:1
+ $Sunrise  = ($Daylight.Sunrise | Get-Date -Format HH:mm).ToLocalTime( ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [API](https://sunrise-sunset.org/api) documentation, you can change the date fomat.
By using **formatted=0** parameter, Get-date will give you the actual time in your time zone.

```
$Daylight = (Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=35.608237&lng=-78.647497&formatted=0").results
$Sunrise  = ($Daylight.Sunrise | Get-Date -Format "HH:mm")
$Sunset   = ($Daylight.Sunset | Get-Date -Format "HH:mm")
```

Edit for yesterday sunset:

If you want the sunset of yesterday, you can ask a specific date to the Rest API:

```
$Yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) | Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
$Daylight = (Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=35.608237&lng=-78.647497&formatted=0&date=$Yesterday").results
$Sunrise  = ($Daylight.Sunrise | Get-Date -Format "HH:mm")
$Sunset   = ($Daylight.Sunset | Get-Date -Format "HH:mm")
```

Comment: I implemented this and it works great.  I added a datestamp back to confirm, and I realized it gives me today's sunrise and sunset.  Which it is supposed to, but I actually need to get yesterday's times.  I tested `(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)` but that won't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean @sbagnato. Unless you're really telling us that you don't want todays sunset and sunrise, but yesterdays!. What surprises me about that is that you must be aware that you can use `date` as well as `lat` and `lng`, and I'd suggest you give it a `relative date`, possibly `yesterday`, although there are other possible options accepted.

Comment: Yes, @Compo, I want yesterday's date.  I did not specify that in the OP as I did not realize until after the script was working that it would not suffice.  My entire script summarizes data from mysql into an easy-to-read email format.  However, certain values don't have much use being averaged at night (solar radiation for instance).  Thus my idea is to only accept the values between sunrise and sunset.

Comment: Does that mean, @sbagnato, that you do, or do not, think that stipulating the `date` option to the api is what you should be doing? instead of getting todays figures and then approximating yesterdays as the same. _(I assume that's what you're doing because if you're only using `HH:mm`, removing `1` day or `24` hours will not modify the output, would it?)_

Comment: No, @Compo I believe you're right and that's what I should be doing.  I will try it out and let you know if it provides what I am looking for.